# Defining wstring after calling / concatenating LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, string, switch-statement, wstring, lpcwstr

I'm tried defining a wstring within a case statement. And trying to access the variable out of the case statement return out of scope.

So I'm now trying to declare a wstring outside of the switch() and define it within the switch(). *But I don't know how to separate those events.*

```
    wstring w1;

    switch (suit)
        {
        case 0:
            std::w1(stringOne);
            break;
        case 1:
            std::w1(stringTwo);
            break;
        case 2:
            std::w1(stringThr);
            break;
        case 3:
            std::w1(stringFou);
            break;
        }
```

Ultimately I'm trying to concatenate (...and listen...) three LPCWSTR's and I'm using `std::wstring` to do that. I'm open to using other means of accomplishing this task.

Comment: Use = to assign strings to w1 inside case statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jumping to a case isn't allowed to skip constructor/destructor calls.  Creating the wstring outside of and before the switch should be fine. You do that by writing:

```
std::wstring wstr;
```

then the switch, and in each relevant case, assigning to the wstr.  Alternatively, under each case open a new block scope in which it is legal to construct a new class.  In code, that would look like:

```
case 0:
{
   std::wstring w;
   // do whatever you want to do with string w...
   // ..
   // then let it 'hit' it's destructor 
}
break;
```